# Generic swap attempt using void**

Tags: c, swap, void-pointers

I'm attempting to swap two values of any given type by swapping their pointers' addresses.

The function I've come up with works fine when called for any two integers, but behaves strangely (to me at least) when more integers are defined in the same scope. For example, consider this SSCCE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void exchx(void** a, void** b) { void* p = *a; *a = *b; *b = p; }

int main(void) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;

    printf("\nBefore: abcd = %d, %d, %d, %d", a, b, c, d);
    exchx((void**)&a,(void**)&b);
    printf("\nAfter: abcd = %d, %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c, d);
}
```

I would expect the second print to be "2, 1, 3, 4", but I get this instead:

```
Before: abcd = 1, 2, 3, 4
After: abcd = 2, 1, 2, 4
```

**I'm sure there are much saner ways to swap data** - that is not the question at all - I'm just curious about this behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: You observe this on 64bit don't you? ;-)

Comment: Another nice example, why (in C) casting mostly never helps, but silencing the compiler.

Comment: Perhaps passing the type size would work.

Comment: @alk Yes, indeed. So you'd say this behavior is specific to my word size?

Comment: Hint: dereferencing a `void**` grabs `sizeof (void*)` bytes which on 64bit (mostly) is more then `sizeof (int)` bytes.

Comment: @brito, on *amd64*, `int` is 4 bytes while `void *` is 8 bytes -- see the problem? -- just don't try *smart-ass* stuff involving casting between data and pointers ;)

Comment: @brito btw, the macro is still nice and generic *as long as* you only use it on actual pointers (called *reference types* in some higher-level languages)

Comment: Uh, my bad, should read *function*, not *macro* ... but it comes down to the same :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, this line

```
exchx((void**)&a,(void**)&b);
```

casts a *pointer to int* to a *pointer to pointer of void*. This just means your `int` gets interpreted *as if it were* a pointer. Expect any strange behaviour doing this.

In short, your `exchx` function is fine for exchanging actual **pointers** ... not for whatever else.

Comment: And may only swap pointers of type `void*`, not any pointer type.